# The type initializer for 'OSGeo.MapGuide.MapGuideApiPINVOKE' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, mapguide

I'm developing a web application on MapGuide Open Source 2.5.2 64bit with ASP.NET. When I try to create a user session from my login.aspx page I get this error:

> The type initializer for 'OSGeo.MapGuide.MapGuideApiPINVOKE' threw an
>   exception

I am using the following code to create the session:

```
try
   {
    MapGuideApi.MgInitializeWebTier (string.Format ("{0} \ \ {1}", serverpath, "webconfig.ini"));
    var site = new MgSite ();
    site.Open (new MgUserInformation (userName, userPassword));
    var sessionID = site.CreateSession ();
    Session.Add ("MgSessionId", sessionID);
    return true;
   }
   catch (MgException exMg)
   {
     this.lblMessage.Text = exMg.Message;
   }
```

Does anyone have ideas about how to fix it? I don't found solutions on the web.
Thanks

Comment: Does the exception contains an inner exception? It might contain something useful.

Comment: It sounds like an error caused by using a static call from a non-static class, or somewhere it shouldn't be...

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't inner exception.

Comment: I tried this procedure other times in php, but I did't have any problems.